# using mod_rewrite for pretty URLs conflict

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 pages for members profile pages and companies profile pages,
for the members the url should be: `site.com/users/USER_ID`
for the companies the url should be: `site.com/COMPANY_ID`

I have this in my `.htaccess`:

```
#Members Profile Page
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ modules/members/members_profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)/$ modules/members/members_profile.php?id=$1

#Companies Profile Page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ modules/companies/companies_profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ modules/companies/companies_profile.php?id=$1
```

But, these 2 rules have conflict which cause the users page also be leaded to `companies_profile.php` since the rule for companies also contain the users profile page in the address.

**UPDATE:**
I've also used **[L]** flag, not working...:

```
#Members Profile Page
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ modules/members/members_profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)/$ modules/members/members_profile.php?id=$1 [L]

#Companies Profile Page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ modules/companies/companies_profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ modules/companies/companies_profile.php?id=$1
```

Still, it is loading `companies_profile.php` for URLs like `/users/etc`..

How I could solve this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here works (/ at the begining) - according to the URL you posted, this will do what you want.

```
#Members Profile Page
RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)$ modules/members/members_profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)/$ modules/members/members_profile.php?id=$1 [L]

#Companies Profile Page
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ modules/companies/companies_profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ modules/companies/companies_profile.php?id=$1
```

What you wrote does not work because "^user/" never matches. Your URL is "/user/". ^ means begining of line. So what you have is not "beginning of line, user" but rather "begining of line, /, user".

Comment: Did that resolve your problem?